# Using onscreenclick only once

Tags: python

I want to make 2 turtles and I want the code to ask the user to select 1 turtle(input) then move the turtle to the mouse position
Then ask again the same question

In my code when one turtle is selected it moves infinite times but I just want to move it once

Comment: Need help! Please

Comment: Provide code! Please

Comment: Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Take the [tour] if you didn't already

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler needs to track the first click. When the first click occurs, stop responding to click events.

Something like the following

```
self.firstClickOccured = False
...
def onClick(self, pos):
    if not self.firstClickOccured:
        #move turtle 1 to pos
        self.firstClickOccured = True
    else:
        #perform logic for 2nd turtle
```

Hopefully you can work from there.

Comment: As described in [answer], please answer only **well-asked** questions. By answering bad questions you are encouraging people to keep asking them...